# Создание ID из индекса и столбца pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Есть несколько файлов `.csv`, в которых хранятся машины, распределенные по маркам (`AUDI.csv`, `FORD.csv` и т.д.). В каждом таком файле есть поле `brand`, где хранится марка автомобиля.

Как в `pandas.Dataframe` сделать столбец `"ID"`, который будет создаваться из индекса строки в DataFrame и из первой и последней буквы поля brand? Результат должен выглядеть так:

```
|index| ID | brand | model |
____________________________
| 0   |AI-0| AUDI  |  TT   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну прямо так как вы и описали в вопросе:

```
df["new"] = df["brand"].str[0] + df["brand"].str[-1] + "-" + df.index.astype(str)
```

результат:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
     ID brand model   new
0  AI-0  AUDI    TT  AI-0
```

Comment: Я понял, что должно быть что-то в таком ключе и попробовал изначально так: 
df["ID"] = df[brand] + "-" + str(df.index)
Но это не дало нужного результата. С чем это связано? (Извините, если это глупый вопрос)

Comment: @Durdma, `df[brand]` - дает вам всю строку целиком - "AUDI", "FORD", etc.. Для вашей задачи удобно использовать "accessor" [Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), который позволяет использовать оператор `[]` как для списков.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что str(df.index) выдавал не то значение, которое я ожидал